# How to remove array wrapper from mariadb server

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to remove the array wrapper surrounding a query result as I'm running a for loop to push the object into an array. This is my query

```
"SELECT * FROM  jobs WHERE id = ? FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER"
```

but I'm getting this result in postman

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER' at line 1"
}
```

Comment: Could you show your desired result, please?

Answer (score 1):

[`for json path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) is a feature of Microsoft SQL Server. There is [a standard for JSON in SQL](https://modern-sql.com/blog/2017-06/whats-new-in-sql-2016), but don't expect most SQL servers to follow it.

---

You can get a single JSON object for each row with [`json_object`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_object/).

```
-- {"id": 2, "name": "Bar"}
select
  json_object('id', id, 'name', name)
from jobs 
where id = 2
```

Rather than query each job individually and then appending to an array, you can do this in single query using the [`in` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_in.asp) to query all desired rows at once, and then [`json_arrayagg`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/) to aggregate them into a single array.

```
-- [{"id": 1, "name": "Foo"},{"id": 3, "name": "Baz"}]
select
  json_arrayagg( json_object('id', id, 'name', name) )
from jobs 
where id in (1, 3)
```

This is much more efficient. In general, if you're querying SQL in loops there's a better way.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=04a4614a62b9aac3f23b79228cf275b1).

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the for json path and found a way to get the result I was looking for. Instead of pushing the object with the array wrapper into the new array, I pushed the array wrapper at index 0 as it's expected to only return one object.